# How can I use addClass in onscroll correctly?

Tags: javascript, scroll, jquery-animate, addclass

I want to create the effect that my page scroll down and the animation being activated.
My animation written by css and gave it a class name 'percent'.My javascript is below:

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
    //onscroll
     window.onscroll = function(){
        var t = document.documentElement.scrollTop || document.body.scrollTop; 
        var set = document.getElementById( "bar1" );
             if( t >= 600 ) {
        set.className = set.className +"percent";

    }
}
   </script>
```

My problem is when my page scroll over 600,the class 'percent' will be added to bar1 repeatly like,

```
 p class="percentpercentpercent... id="bar1"
```

How could I do about it?
Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check before adding the class:

```
if((set.className).indexOf("percent") == -1){
    set.className = set.className +"percent";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First check if it has the class (set.classList.contains('percent')) and if not then only add

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    //onscroll
     window.onscroll = function(){
        var t = document.documentElement.scrollTop || document.body.scrollTop; 
        var set = document.getElementById( "bar1" );
             if( t >= 600 and !set.classList.contains('percent')) {
        set.className = set.className +" percent";

    }
}
   </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The "percent" is getting appended on to itself when you scroll past 600px. Try just setting it once.

```
if( t >= 600){
  set.className == "percent" || set.className = "percent";
}
```

Comment: thxs your answer,but I try this code on my page firefox say"ReferenceError: invalid assignment left-hand side "